# laravel component in foreach loop, other elements are grouped

Tags: laravel

If I do this (`$favorites` is a collection):

```
@if($favorites and $favorites->isNotEmpty())
  @foreach($favorites as $f)

    @component('components.favorite', [
      'f' => $f
    ])
    @endcomponent

    <button>Test</button>

  @endforeach
@endif
```

and there's 3 objects in the collection, the resulting HMTL is the following:

```
component
button
button
button
component
component
```

while I'm expecting this:

```
component
button
component
button
component
button
```

which seems logical from the way the foreach loop is defined?